# disable dates in jQuery datepicker with dates from MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm trying to disable certain dates from jQuery datepicker. I know this subject is talked about often but usually only in regards to regulars dates such as holidays or weekends. I'd like to pull the days from a MySQL table instead. For disabling regular dates the codes is;

```
$(function() {
  $("#datepickerthing").datepicker({ 
    altField: '#actualDate', 
    minDate:'0', 
    maxDate: '+6M',
    beforeShowDay:  nationalDays
  });

  var natDays = ["4/22/2009","4/23/2009","4/24/2009","4/25/2009","4/26/2009","5/27/2009","5/28/2009","6/26/2009","6/27/2009","6/28/2009","6/29/2009","6/30/2009"];
  function nationalDays(date) {
    var sDate = (date.getMonth()+1).toString() + "/" + date.getDate().toString() + "/" + date.getFullYear().toString();
    if ($.inArray(sDate, natDays) != -1) return [false,"","Not this day!"];
    else return [true, ""];
  }
});
```

What I don't understand is how to get a string of dates from a database into the variable "natDays" and make sure they are formatted properly.

Thanks in advance for any help anyone can offer.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to make an Ajax request.

1. Script in PHP to create a string of properly formatted dates from your database
2. Return this string from the ajax request
3. `.split()` them into your array variable.

To properly format your dates, I'd recommend `explode()`ing them from your database, then dropping them into something like `date("m/d/y",mktime(0,0,0,4,5,2010))` (the `4,5,2010` comes from your exploded date).